# Why do certain Stack Exchange sites have top level domains while others don't?

Tags: discussion

This is just a question of curiosity:

Why do certain SE sites (for instance Superuser and Stack Overflow) have top level domains (superuser.com and stackoverflow.com), while other sites that have been around a while and have a decent following don't have one (for instance The Workplace - workplace.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a site-wide question. Try asking on [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com). Mods should be able to move this though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

History lesson: Stack Overflow was the first site to be launched. It was a resounding success and shortly Server Fault, Meta Stack Overflow & Super User were launched later.

Based on success of these sites, Stack Overflow begins to offer Stack Exchange 1.0, as a white-labelled solution. [It didn't go too well, and SE1.0 was canned](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/). In the interim, [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) is launched, allowing for [new sites to be proposed by the community](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-first-public-beta/).

The initial Stack Exchange sites start to grow. [Stack Exchange gets spun into Stack Exchange 2.0, a network-wide aggregator of all Stack Exchange sites](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/network-central-stackexchange-com/).

Stack Exchange 2.0 sites initially were to get [individual domains](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/). Web Applications goes live as [Nothing To Install](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/). Marco Arment [mentions us](http://www.marco.org/2010/10/01/nothing-to-install-launched). [Jeff & co do a volte-face](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/), say Domains are Bad, topic.stackexchange.com goooooood.

Since he was BDFL then, the naming stuck. Despite overwhelming wishes against this from the [community](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/629/310)

<sup><sup><sup>yes, I'm still a little bitter about that.</sup></sup></sup>

Comment: Further reading: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/stack-exchange-naming-for-dummies/ http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/ http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/06/welcome-to-the-arqade/

Comment: Do you know why Ask Ubuntu gets to use the domain for more than a redirect even though it's (slightly) younger than Webapps?

Comment: @DanielBeck apparently some partnership bs http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/ubuntu-stack-exchange-is-askubuntu-com/

Comment: Thanks! I got rate-limited while digging out the old posts, so I didn't find that one.